# bibliography in cvitem (moderncv)

Tags: bibtex, moderncv

I would like to split my publications in several subsections. Instead of subsection titles I would like to write the titles within the first column.

Looking at the MWE attached below I would like the subsection title on the right (like Articles) but with the same location of the body as in the first part - just without the section title on top of it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{somewhere}{}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}  

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{article,book}{{},{Books}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle

    % Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
    \section{Publications}
    \nocitebook{A}
    \nocitebook{B}
    \bibliographystylebook{unsrt}
    \bibliographybook{test}

    \nocitearticle{C}
    \nocitearticle{D}
    \bibliographystylearticle{unsrt}
    \cvitem{Articles}{\bibliographyarticle{test}}

    \clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\newcites{article,book}{{Articles},{Books}}` Add *Articles* there and leave out the `\cvitem` and call the bibliogrphy lie you did for books. Ah no, you wnt it the other way around.

Comment: Honestly, i would use `biblatex` for the job, it is easier.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion using `biblatex` with a very manual hack to avoid the vertical space (not shown in the picture).

[image: maguModerncvBibliogrphy]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{somewhere}{}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}  

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\nocite{aksin,angenendt,aristotle:physics,aristotle:anima}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{}
\section{Publications}
\cvitem{\rlap{\rule{4cm}{.1pt}}Books}{\vspace{-4.1ex}\printbibliography[type=book]}
\cvitem{\rlap{\rule{4cm}{.1pt}}Articles}{\vspace{-4.3ex}\printbibliography[type=article]}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that could work. One more question though, can I align the side title with the first citation?

Comment: @magu_ See edit.